# Extracting coordinates from meshgrid data

Tags: python, numpy, mesh

I have a cubic grid as shown in the picture below.

I would like to list the vertices of each sub-cube, so I would end up with a nested list of sub-cubes with their corresponding list of vertices.

My initial attempt was to use a generator,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

dims = [9,9,9]    
spacer = 3
subBoxCoords = np.array([(x, y, z) for x in range(0, dims[0], spacer) for y in range(0, dims[1], spacer) for z in range(0, dims[2], spacer)])
ax.scatter(subBoxCoords[:,0], subBoxCoords[:,1], subBoxCoords[:,2], c='k', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
```

This does give me the desired shape but coordinates are ordered in a manner that vertices extraction of the sub-boxes is not straight forward. Also I would like to generalize this to boxes of arbitrary dimension so hard coding in intervals is not a solution.

So, then I thought I would use `meshgrid`,

```
nx,ny, nz = (3,3,3)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, nx)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, ny)
z = np.linspace(0, 10, nz)
xv, yv, zv = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='xy')

ax.scatter(xv, yv, zv, c='g', marker='^')
```

This appears to be a very powerful way to achieve what I want but I am getting confused. Is there a direct way access vertices in the `meshgrid` in the manner `vertex(x,y,z)`? Or even a straight forward way to extract sub-cubes?

It seems to me that the solution is tantalizingly close but I just cant grasp it!

[image: Cubic grid]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`meshgrid` is probably what you need, but the shape of the array returned by `meshgrid` is where it gets confusing. Meshgrid returns three coordinate arrays, all the same shape. The shape of each of `xv, yv, zv` is `(len(x), len(y), len(z))`. So, to extract the coordinate at the corner `(0, 2, 1)`, you would write `xv[0, 2, 1], yv[0, 2, 1], zv[0, 2, 1]`

To extract all of the subcubes' corners' coordinates, it helps to observe that, because of the way the arrays returned by `meshgrid` are ordered sequentially, `xv[:-1, :-1, :-1]` returns only the x-coordinates of the near-left-bottom corners of each subcube. Likewise, `xv[1:, 1:, 1:]` returns the far-right-top corners of each subcube. The other six corners are given by the other six combinations of the slices `:-1` and `1:` (`xv[:-1, 1:, :-1]` gives the far-left-top corner, for example).

So, iterate through all eight combinations of `:-1` and `1:` to get eight parallel arrays of three parallel arrays of x, y, z coordinates for the eight corners of all `len(x)-1 * len(y-1) * len(z-1)` subcubes. (If you need your subcube corner coordinate arrays to be in a particular shape or axis order, or if you want to use a single index to specify the subcube rather than three, use `rollaxis`, `swapaxis` and `shape` as needed.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import itertools

nx, ny, nz = (3,3,3)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, nx)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, ny)
z = np.linspace(0, 10, nz)
xv, yv, zv = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='xy')


slices = slice(None, -1), slice(1, None)
cornerSlices = list(itertools.product(slices, slices, slices))
corners = np.array([(xv[s], yv[s], zv[s]) for s in cornerSlices])

# The shape of `corners` is `(len(cornerSlices), 3, len(x-1), len(y-1), len(z-1)`
# The axes of `corners` represent, in the same order: the corner index; the cartesian 
# coordinate axis (the index into [x, y, z]); the x, y, and z indexes of the subcube. 

# Plot the first subcube (subcube 0, 0, 0)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

subcube = corners[:, :, 0, 0, 0]
subcubeX = subcube [:, 0]
subcubeY = subcube [:, 1]
subcubeZ = subcube [:, 2]

ax.scatter(subcubeX , subcubeY , subcubeZ , c='g', marker='^')
```

[image]

There's invariably a way to get the indexes into `xv, yv, zv` instead of getting the values, since the values are duplicated quite a few times in the `corners` array. It would involve slicing arrays of indexes into `xv, yv, zv` instead of slicing the arrays themselves. My head is already spinning after getting this far into the ndarray voodoo, so I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: The exposition was well needed thanks. I was wondering about memory issues with `meshgrid`? (I have potentially very large grids which was why I went down the generator route initially)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly -

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,3)
xs = np.array(np.meshgrid(x,x,x))
points = np.transpose(xs.reshape(3,-1))
points
```